# Visual Studio 2003 and satellite assemblies

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2003 project and I have set all of the AssemblyInfo fields.

```
<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("FooBar")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("FooBar Desc")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("FooBar CO")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("FooBar")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("FooBar 2009")>
```

These fields are correctly included in compiled assembly, but they aren't included in projects satellite assemblies (*.resources.dll).

Is there any way to include assembly infos to resource satellite assemblys in Visual Studio 2003?

Comment: It seems that this is feature/bug in VS 2003. Assembly version is correctly assigned, but not the Company or Product -fields.

It works properly in VS 2005 and VS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is feature/bug in VS 2003. Assembly version is correctly assigned, but not the Company or Product -fields.

It works properly in VS 2005 and VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to link/share the AssemblyInfo.cs (or AssemblyInfo.vb) file with your satallite assemblies. Try read this: http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18855 or watching this video from DimeCasts http://dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/10

Comment: This is not what I had in mind.. I meant the resource files, which are generated when the project is compiled. IE. All the "localization"-strings and stuff are in these satellite assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the **/template** option for **Al.exe**

> The /template option specifies an assembly from which to inherit all assembly metadata, except the culture field. The assembly that the satellite assembly inherits from must have a [strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx).

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht.aspx